# How to set value on searchbar Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4, searchbar

I'm trying to set value on searchbar but cannot see any example, just what i want is to put a value of a list into the searchbar (to do an autocomplete searchbar), i've done this code:

HTML

```
    <ion-searchbar type="text" debounce="500" animated 
    placeholder="Filtrar por país" color="dark"
    (ionChange)="search($event)" clearInput></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let country of countries" (click)="selectCountry($country)">
        {{ country }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

TS

```
    search(event) {
    console.log(event)
    this.initializeListCountries();
    console.log(this.countries)
    const val = event.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
        this.countries = this.countries.filter((country) => {
            return (country.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
    }
}

selectCountry(country) {
    let val = country.target.value;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you need to declare the **selectedCountry** variable in the class and assign the selected country to that variable then you need to bind that variable in the template like this  `[value]="selectedCountry"`

> **Solution**

**HTML**

```
   <ion-searchbar type="text" debounce="500" animated 
    placeholder="Filtrar por país" color="dark" 
    [value]="selectedCountry"
    (ionChange)="search($event)" clearInput></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let country of countries" (click)="selectCountry(country)">
        {{ country }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**TS**

```
selectedCountry: string;//declare global variable

selectCountry(country) {
    this.selectedCountry = country; //assign value

}
```

Comment: This is angular or typescript way?

Comment: Buddy, it gives error, cannot find "target", maybe theres something wrong?

Comment: The parameter of selecCountry function should be a string as well: `selectCountry(country: string) {
    this.selectedCountry = country; //assign value
}`

Comment: please console log the country

Comment: undefined it says

Comment: so please remove $ sign before the country variable in template.

Comment: please check updated answer it will work as expected